# no lpr or lprng file in /etc/int.d/

Tags: 18.04, firefox, printing, evince, etc

My printer is behaving randomly except for the test page. It always works well on test page.

Sometimes it works well on all applications.

Sometimes it works on Chrome, chromium, but not on Firefox and pdf readers.

Next time it works well on all browsers and not on pdf readers.

Next time it does not work on any application except test page.

But, it always show led signal whenever I give print command. And also it shows printing and printed, without being printed.

The printer is HL-L2321D and I am [following instructions](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=in&lang=en&prod=hll2321d_as&os=128) from their site. The instructions are from [here](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=in&lang=en&prod=hll2321d_as&os=128&dlid=dlf101908_000&flang=4&type3=559) and [here](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=in&lang=en&prod=hll2321d_as&os=128&dlid=dlf101909_000&flang=4&type3=561).

So, I tried on installing all related drivers. One of the last instruction is to restart `lpr` or `lprng` in `/etc/int.d`. But I don't have such file.

Comment: `locate lpr` shows me these files are in `/usr/bin/` in my system. Also, please edit your post with the troubleshooting guide you followed so we are on the same page, all together with your printer model and how it is connected to your system (wifi, wired) and could help people with similar issues.

Also, a simple restart of your system should also work.

Comment: @B.duGaray Restart is working for sometimes... And does not work sometimes... seems full random....

Comment: "/etc/int.d. But I don't have such file." I think you will find it is actually named `init.d` and is a directory

Answer (score 1):

To get `lprng` init script you have to install [corresponding package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=lprng) by

```
sudo apt-get install lprng
```

---

For linux driver see https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=in&lang=en&prod=hll2321d_as&os=128 .